# Why is this node's X position not the center of the screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a container node, simply initialized with no arguments. When added to the scene it appeared centered, as all children nodes are placed approriately.
 
Then in touchesMoved I'm trying to use the following code to allow movement of the container node up to 1/3 of the screen width in either X direction:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
    let width = self.frame.size.width
    let startX = touch!.previousLocation(in: self).x
    let currentX = touch!.location(in: self).x

    if container.position.x < width * CGFloat(5.0/6.0) && container.position.x > width * CGFloat(1.0/6.0) {
        container.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: (currentX - startX), y: 0.0, duration: 0.0))
    }

}
```

Removing the if statement conditionals, but keeping the code inside the if, allows for the container to be moved indefintely without bounds, but with the if statement it will not move at all.  It seems to me that the x position of the container should start at the center (width * 3/6) and  these conditions should allow it to move in either direction to the bounds by allowing movement between (width * 1/6) and (width * 5/6).  Is this the wrong way to go about this, or is my logic flawed?

Comment: what is the scene anchorPoint ? what is container (SpriteNode or SKNode)? what is the anchor point of the container if it is a SpriteNode?

Comment: What do you think the position of the center of the screen is?